# Why is `throw` invalid in an ES6 arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm just looking for a reason as to *why* this is invalid:

```
() => throw 42;
```

I know I can get around it via:

```
() => {throw 42};
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you don't use a block (`{}`) as body of an [arrow function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions), the body must be an [**expression**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-expressions):

```
ArrowFunction:
    ArrowParameters[no LineTerminator here] => ConciseBody

ConciseBody:
    [lookahead ≠ { ] AssignmentExpression
    { FunctionBody }
```

But `throw` is a [*statement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations), not an expression.

---

In theory

```
() => throw x;
```

is equivalent to

```
() => { return throw x; }
```

which would not be valid either.

Answer (score 5):

You can't `return throw` this is effectively what you're trying to do:

```
function(){
  return throw 42;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you omit the braces in an arrow function, you create [an implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body), which is equivalent to creating an explicit return with the braces, like so: `() => { return throw 42 };`

However, you can only return [expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators), not [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements). And `throw` is a statement.

Answer (score -1):

To hack around you could wrap a `throw` using function. Then use it as a part of expression.

```
function explode (str?: string) { throw new Error(str) };
const oups = () => explode("42");
oups();
```

```
function explode (str?: string) { throw new Error(str) };
const input: null | number = null;
const output = (input ?? explode("input should not be null")) + 42;
```