# How to write a one line callback arrow function to throw error?

Tags: javascript

How can I write this simple callback with arrow function?

```js
(error) => {
  throw error
}
```

The following doesn't work:

```js
(error) => throw error
```

Comment: `(error) => {  throw error }` - there, that's one line ... some operations just need the `{}` - though ... depending on the context, you may get away with the following code - no code at all - ... again, depends on the context of that code - show some more context and I'll let you know if ANY code is needed at all

Comment: Felix Kling explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109822/why-is-throw-invalid-in-an-es6-arrow-function

Answer (score 4):

`throw` is a statement (something that *does* something), and not an expression (which evaluates to a value).

When using concise body syntax - an arrow function without a `{` following `=>` - what follows the `=>` must be an expression. So, `(error) => throw error` doesn't work - your only option is to put the `throw` in the context of somewhere where an expression is permitted, which will have to be inside a block:

```
(error) => {
  throw error
}
```

You can put it all on one line if you want, but the brackets will still be required:

```
(error) => { throw error }
```

I suppose you could use a concise body for the outer function and put in an IIFE which makes a new block, inside of which `throw` will be permitted, but that adds syntax noise for no real gain IMO:

```
(error) => (() => { throw error })();
```

[Throw expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-throw-expressions) are at stage 2. Eventually, it may well be possible to use `throw` like you want, with a concise body - but it's not possible quite yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use a block like {} as body of an arrow function , the body must be an expression. Like if you use

```
(error) => throw error
```

is equivalent to

```
(error) => { return throw error; }
```

throw is a statement not expression , that's why it is not valid. So you have to define like below:

```
(error) => {throw error};
```